# Matlab: indexes and associated values

Tags: matlab, indexing

First of all, my programming skills are not that great, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to script the following in Matlab, R2015a:

1) Given a certain vector (`mag`), calculates two notable values from the first 300 values of that vector (`Am` and `A`);

2) Gets the indexes of the value of `Am`, and the two indexes of the value `A` (the vector is symmetric, so there will be two indexes for `A`);

3) Gets the values (`fm`, `f1` and `f2`) associated with the three previous indexes (index from `Am`, first `A` and second `A` respectively) from another vector (`freq`).

4) Finally, calculate `D` based on the values in 3).

So far, this is what I've got:

```
Am=max(mag(1:300));   %Am is the maximum value of vector mag  
A=Am/2^0.5;           %A is the other desired value

[~,Im] = mag(1:300,Am);  %Trying to get the Am index. Error: "Indexing cannot yield multiple results." I found that this error is usual when using variables with the same name, which is not the case.  
fm=freq(Im);  %Value of freq associated with Am

[~,I1] = mag(1:300,A,'first'); %Index of the first value of A  
f1=freq(I1) ;                   %Value of freq associated with the first value of A

[~,I2] = mag(1:300,A,'second'); %Index of the second value of A  
f2=freq(I1);                     %Value of freq associated with the second value of A

D=(f2^2-f1^2)/(4*fm)
```

I'm having trouble getting the associated `freq` values from the desires values of `mag`.Any tips and suggestions are more than welcome.

And thank you in advance!

Comment: Found out that I can replace [~,Im] = mag(1:300,Am) by

[~,I1] = max(mag(1:300))

Which works fine. Problem still persists for the other two indexes.

Comment: in your first piece of code you are using `mag` as a variable, further on as a function. Nothing makes really sense here.

Comment: @ thewaywewalk, if you are reffering to the attempt of getting the indexes from the two values of *A*, ignore what's there. I can't seem to find a way to do it, and that was a bad attempt, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here some suggestions:

```
%find the index of a certain value
l1=find(mag(1:300)==Am);

% find the first index
l2=find(mag(1:300)==Am, 'first');
```

usually, if you have a vector with indices, then you can use that to get the value of another vector, like

```
a=[1 3 6 8];
b=rand(10,1);
b(a) % yields the first, third, sixth and eighth value of b
```

Keep in mind, the index-vector needs to be integer type, else it won't work. 
Can you maybe post the precise error message and maybe also an example of mag?

hope this helps

Comment: "Error using find
Second argument must be a positive scalar integer.", when using l2=find(mag(1:300)==Am, 'first');

*mag* is a 3908x1 double, the abs() of an Fast Fourier Transform.

Also, is it possible to replace 'first' for 'second', the get the second index?

Comment: l2=find(mag(1:300)==Am, 1, 'first');